# Distributed search in SOLR

Tags: solr, distributed-system

I am using SOLR 1.3.0 for performing a distributed search over already existing lucene indices. The question is, is there any way in which I could find from which shard did a result come up after the search?

P.S : I am using the REST api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Solr sharding -

> Documents must have a unique key and the unique key must be stored
>   (stored="true" in schema.xml)

I think the logic should be already there on your side, by which you are feeding the data to the shards, as the ids need to be unique.
e.g. the simplest is the odd even combination, but you may have some complex ones by which you distribute the data into the shards.

Comment: That is the problem with my use case. The lucene indexes already written do not have an uuid. May be I should go with a workaround

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to get some information using debugQuery=on, but if this is something that you'll query often I'd add a specific stored field for the shard name.

PS: Solr doesn't have a REST API.

Comment: +1 for the approach. But why Solr doesn't have a REST api? Isn't "/select?q=something" a REST API call?

Comment: @Roman : one of REST's main concepts is that the API is driven by hypermedia. But there is no hypermedia whatsoever in Solr's current API. See http://robmcgrail.com/code/solr-s-rest-interface-isn-t-really for more details.

Comment: Ok! Chuck the API thing, I am querying it via an URL.

How does debugQuery help? I don't find anything tangible. Any help would be great Mauricio!

Comment: @MauricioScheffer What I like the most is the background of the site you mentioned :)